# Django Admin: Custom form to add a link at top of the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the admin form as below:

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'city', 'state', 'country')
```

On the edit form page `/admin/my_app/item/1/change/`, I want to add a custom link at the top of the page, so admin can click on the link to view the actual item page on a public-facing website.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}
    {% if adminform.form.instance.id %}
        <a href="{% url 'place' slug=adminform.form.instance.slug %}"> Public View </a><br/><br/>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```